# RandomRange TMemo Lines

Tags: windows, delphi, line, memo

I would pick a random line from Memo1 and then run it as a link, I tried this code:

```
ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', PAnsiChar(RandomRange(Memo1.Lines[1], Memo1.Lines.Count)), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL) ;
```

But an error appears:

```
Unit1.pas(86): E2010 Incompatible types: 'Integer' and 'string'
```

So my question is: How do I pick a random line from TMemo?

Thank you.

Comment: When you want to figure out how to do something, like "pick a random line from Memo1", then write a test app that does just that, and figure out how to make it work, without doing anything else like `ShellExecute`. It's much easier to tell where the problem is that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should be

```
ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', PChar(Memo1.Lines[RandomRange(0, Memo1.Lines.Count-1)]), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL) ;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but another little question: how do I open the link on the same page? Thank you very much

Comment: If you want to ask a different question, please do just that.

Comment: I see you asked a different question. Good. But please don't forget to accept the answer here.